# javascript - app.set('port', 8080) versus app.listen(8080) in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I've been trying to use Express.js to launch a website. At first, I was using
`app.set('port', 8080)` but the browser was unable to connect to the page. Afterwards, I changed the code to `app.listen(8080)` and the webpage appeared normally.

This led me to wonder, what is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`app.set('port', 8080)` is similar to setting a "variable" named `port` to `8080`, which you can access later on using `app.get('port')`. Accessing your website from the browser will really not work because you still didn't tell your app to listen and accept connections.

`app.listen(8080)` on the other hand listens for connections at port `8080`. This is the part where you're telling your app to listen and accept connections. Accessing your app from the browser using `localhost:8080` will work if you have this in your code.

The two commands can actually be used together:

```
app.set('port', 8080);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's common practice to store the port value using `app.set`, or why anything would ever be stored here instead of in ordinary variables?

Comment: @GershomMaes storing the port value using `app.set` might be a bad example here, but for other values it makes sense to store them using `app.set` instead of in ordinary variables, just like for example `app.set('views', 'somepath');` which tells express where to look for views. Values stored using `app.set` could be used internally in express or some other packages that your app uses.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple enough to declare a variable server at the bottom of the page and define the port that you want.  You can console.log the port so that it will be visible in the command line.

```
var server = app.listen(8080,function(){
   console.log('express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    })
```

Comment: Just a heads up, `port` is no longer a function.  In the above example: `server.address().port` will work.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
var port = 8080
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
```

Line by Line Explaination:

`var port = 8080;` =>Creates a variable(everything in javascript is an object) and sets the port location to localhost 8080 `app.listen(port);`
=>The application made using express module checks for any connections available and if yes then it connects and the application launches
`console.log('Listening on port ' + port);` =>Displays the message onto the terminal once deployed successfully